# How to write scripts with some logic between two tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my questions in writing some scripts in MySQL:

I get a table `T1` with some columns called id, `t1_col_01, t1_col_02`, and a table `T2` with some columns called `id, t2_col_01, t2_col_02`.

For each row `R1` in `T1`, I want to update `R1.t1_col_01 = 'Yes'` if the there are multiple rows in `T2` that has the same `id` column with `R1.id`. If not, set `R1.t1_col_01 = 'No'`.

I tried to write:

```
update T1, T2
set
    T1.t1_col_01 = 'Yes'
where
    (select count(*) from T2 where T2.id = T1.id) > 1
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Provide tables schema, sample data, what you expected it to do, what it did (error or unexpected outcome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is this:

```
update T1 
     inner join T2 
     on ( T2.id = T1.id )
   set T1.t1_col_01 = 'Yes'
 where (select count(*) from T2 where T2.id = T1.id) > 1
```

See it here on fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0edc4/1